# Facing error while updating google add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api, chrome-web-store

I am having the owner role of the Google docs add-on and when I try to update the add-on using google script then it displays error: **You do not have access to change this item.**

I am trying to publish that update from here: Publish > Deploy as an add-on.

Let me know if I am missing any step or how I can publish the update.

Comment: You are missing many steps.  The process of publishing an add-on can't be fully explained here in the comments section.  Information about publishing an add-on is provided in the documentation.  Unfortunately, the documentation is a little difficult to find at the moment.  [Link to Publishing an editor add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-editor-addons)  Please read the documentation at the link provided.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this issue after changing ownership of an appscript project.

> cause: the chrome webstore item is still linked to a chrome webstore item (of the owner)

### FIX #1 (preferrred)

Using the old account, go to the chrome webstore developer dashboard and somehow share or transfer the webstore item.
This can be done by adding the new user to a group, and moving the webstore item to that group.
disclaimer: I haven't tried this recently (I went for FIX #2, but I have done this fix in the past)

### FIX #2: link to new chrome webstore item

1. Go to Publish > Register in Chrome Webstore
2. delete the chrome webstore item / instance (there's a link in the dialog)
3. Go to Publish > Deploy as Addon
4. Profit!

> NOTE: obviously users of the old addon will not be affected, and new webstore item-updates will not drip into the old webstore-item.